# What is the exact requirement for defining a python tp_call function?

Tags: python, callable

I am binding C++ classes to Python and have come to an interesting solution to a previous problem, unfortunately this has lead to another question that there seems to be no easy answer too. 

I am wrapping each function into a "callable" PyObject, what makes it callable is having the **call** function define (C side this is the tp_call method in the PyTypeObject).

The tp_call seems to take a ternary function which just accepts (PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*) as its argument list.
Now the problem is that I need for this function to just take the place of the PyCFunction, which just takes the arguments (PyObject* self, PyObject* args). Now python side this can be done easily, but C side it seems to need the ternary function when I just want a binary one,
so is there anyway to make the callable function simple take the PyCFunction pointer or a way to encapsulate it as such?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third `PyObject*` is the kwargs. Write a wrapper that just... doesn't pass them. Raising `TypeError` if it contains anything is optional.

Comment: Well that works, it just looks... messy compared to any other options. I guess I can just do this =)